# Cisco Router configuration prompt not working

Tags: cisco, ios

First of all I am new to Cisco, We are moving from an old T1 to Fiber Optic and I need to configure our Cisco 1841 router to the new IP, DNS, etc.

I watch some videos and I get the overall concept but I am having problems even logging into the console, I am logging in using PuTTY over SSH ad I am asked for log in and password and it works.

The problem is when I get the command prompt, it doesn't look like any of the tutorials I've seen. it looks something like this: [root@ody2 ~]#

which to me looks more like a Unix prompt than cisco ios, I tried to execute some commands like "show running" but all I get is "-bash: show: command not found".

any leads on what am doing wrong will be appreciated.

I like to add that I am unable to use telnet, the command window opens and closes immediately without letting me type anything.

Comment: Read this and then try connecting with telnet: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/configuration/guide/15_1s/cf_15_1s_book/cf_cli-basics.html

Comment: Is there a linux/pfsense/etc box acting as a nat/firewall/etc between you and the 1841? A traceroute could provide some information since LAN connecions are usually ~1ms and serial connectivity adds 10+ ms of latency.

Answer (score 1):

It does not sound like you are connected to the router at all as you suspected.

Are you sure that ssh is even enabled on  the cisco box ?

Has the box been set up or is it new ?

I would connect up a console cable and login that way can't go wrong then.

Comment: Thank you, That was my next step to try, I'm just waiting for a serial/usb adapter to arrive. I inherited this system and still learning it.